# How can I use "or", "and" in C# Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a pattern to match with the string:
string pattern = @"asc"
I am checking the SQL SELECT query for right syntax, semantics, ...
I need to say that in the end of the query string I can have "asc" or "desc".
How can it be written in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That'd look like

```
new Regex("asc$|desc$").IsMatch(yourQuery)
```

assuming that you're mandating that asc/desc is the end of the query.  You could also do `(?:asc|desc)$` which is a little cleaner with the single `$`, but less readable.

Answer (score 1):

You want the "alternation" operator, which is the pipe.

For instance, I believe this would be represented as:

```
asc|desc
```

If you want to make it a non-capturing group you can do it in the normal way. I'm not a regex expert, but that's the first thing to try.

EDIT: MSDN has a page about [regular expression language elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) which may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the other answers, you probably wanna apply an ignore case option to the regex as well.

```
string tempString = "SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY column DESC";

Regex r = new Regex("asc$|desc$", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

bool answer = r.IsMatch(tempString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I reckon something like the following works as a regex in .Net:

```
asc|desc\z
```

.. it will match end of line as well as end of string. If you just want end of string try:

```
asc|desc$
```